# Can't communicate MultiPart/data in Test (Jersey/Junit)

Tags: java, maven, junit, jersey

So i've had some trouble with doing Unit test of a method that parse PDFs

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response parsingPdfOrange(@FormDataParam("fichier") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("fichier") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {

    try {

        String uploadedFileLocation = "D:/tmp/doc.pdf";

        String info = "facture Orange:"
                + OrangeService.ParseFacture(uploadedFileLocation, uploadedInputStream).toString();

        return Response.status(201).entity(info).build();
```

which works fine my url give my the good result etc but

```
    @Override
protected Application configure() {
    return new ResourceConfig(OrangeWebService.class).register(MultiPartFeature.class);

}

@Override
protected void configureClient(ClientConfig config) {
    config.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
}

@Test
public void parsePDF_NullPointerExcpetion() throws Exception {
    try {

        FileDataBodyPart filePart = new FileDataBodyPart("file", new File(pathtoRessources));
        FormDataMultiPart formDataMultipart = new FormDataMultiPart();
        FormDataMultiPart multipart = (FormDataMultiPart) formDataMultipart.bodyPart(filePart);

        Response response = (target("pdf").request().post(Entity.entity(multipart, multipart.getMediaType())));

        System.out.println(response);
        response.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

this is my test code and the pb is here: it seems my FormDataMultiPart is fine but when i do Entity.entity(multipart, multipart.getMediaType() it gives back a null value because i get a nullPointerException on it.

I need help, Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace

Comment: Also if you can, please make the test _complete and runnable_ like [this example](https://gist.github.com/psamsotha/13fe79f0e572bbbec6ca486e4501fe5a), where we can just copy and paste the whole thing and run it as is. That means remove the `OrangeService` if it is not part of the problem. Replace it with something else. This is what we call an [MCVE]. It's easier to solve the problem if we can easily reproduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file part name is `"fichier"`

```
@FormDataParam("fichier") InputStream uploadedInputStream
```

But you are sending it as `"file"`

```
FileDataBodyPart filePart = new FileDataBodyPart("file", new File(pathtoRessources));
```

Fix that.